# jQuery wrap multiple elements independent of level

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

This is my first post on stackoverflow. So far I could always find an answer here, but this time I couldn't.

Here is my DOM structure:

```
<div id="elementA">
    <div id="elementB"></div>
    <div id="elementC">
         <div id="elementD"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="elementE"></div>
</div>
```

How can I wrap 2 or more selected "random" elements into a wrapper container? This should also work if the selected elements are on different level and if there are other elements in between. The DOM structure of all other elements shouldn't be effected.

Following a few examples:

**Example 1:**

I though of something like this:

```
var element1 = $('#elementB');
var element2 = $('#elementE');

??? $(element1, element2).myWrap(".wrapper"); ???
```

Result should look like this:

```
<div id="elementA">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="elementB"></div>    
        <div id="elementC">
             <div id="elementD"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="elementE"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**2 Example:**

Elements are in different levels.

```
var element1 = $('#elementD');
var element2 = $('#elementE');

??? $(element1, element2).myWrap(".wrapper"); ???
```

Result:

```
<div id="elementA">
    <div id="elementB"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="elementC">
             <div id="elementD"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="elementE"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Example 3:** More than 2 elements:

```
var element1 = $('#elementD');
var element2 = $('#elementC');
var element3 = $('#elementA');

??? $(element1, element2, element3).myWrap(".wrapper"); ???

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="elementA">
        <div id="elementB"></div>    
        <div id="elementC">
             <div id="elementD"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="elementE"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Example 4:** Different trees:

```
var element1 = $('#elementD');
var element2 = $('#elementF');

??? $(element1, element2).myWrap(".wrapper"); ???


<div id="elementA">
    <div id="elementB"></div>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="elementC">
             <div id="elementD"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="elementE">
             <div id="elementF"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't figure out the algorithm you are trying to do. Right now, when you call wrap on and E you loop in C also. But in the other example when you call wrap on D and E you don't loop in B. It's the same situation, looping in a sibling, but in one case it acts differently. If you know a way to reconcile that then it's solvable.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to wrap 2 elements wherever they appear in the DOM with one single wrapper. Meaning, if they appear in separate trees, the wrapper should be in the first common outer tree. Does that make sense? I will add another example.

Comment: Your example still does not clarify why in example 1, the wrapper wraps a sibling, but in example two, it doesn't. Either the siblings need to get wrapped always, or you need to have two wrappers in example 1. Currently the result seems, well, random, and randomness is very hard to program.

Comment: It seems to me like the author is trying to find the "greatest common factor" of these elements' hierarchy; the first parent that they all have in common - and insert the wrapper around them and inside that parent.

Comment: Thats right Mike. Thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments above, the first example is different to the others in that when the specified children are all direct decendants, then all children in the common parent should be wrapped.

Using this logic, the following solution works.

```
jQuery.fn.myWrap = function(options) {
    var e = this;

    // find most nested
    var max = null;
    var $mostNested = null;

    $(e).each(function(i, elem) {
        var parents = $(elem).parents().length;
        if (parents > max || max == null) {
            max = parents;
            $mostNested = $(elem);
        }
    })

    // find common parent
    var found = false;
    $parent = $mostNested.parent();
    while($parent != null && !found) {
        if ($parent.find(e).length == e.length) {
            // Right Level
            found = true;
            var toWrap = [];
            var numDirect = 0;
            $.each($parent.children(), function(i, item) {
                var direct = $(e).index(item) >= 0;
                var sibling = $(item).find(e).length > 0;
                if (direct) numDirect++;
                if (direct || sibling) toWrap.push(item);
            })
            if (numDirect == e.length) {
                // All direct! (Example 1)
                $parent.children().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
            } else {
                // Other Examples
                $(toWrap).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
            }
        }
        $parent = $parent.parent();    
    }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    // Example 1
    $('#elementB, #elementE').myWrap();
    // Example 2
    //$('#elementD, #elementE').myWrap();
    // Example 3
    //$('#elementD, #elementC, #elementA').myWrap();
    // Example 4
    //$('#elementD, #elementF').myWrap();
})
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BcXW/4/).