# jQuery wrap multiple elements independent of level and preserve white space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791765/jquery-wrap-multiple-elements-independent-of-level) to wrap elements. It works perfectly, but as jQuery's `.wrapAll` gets rid of all white space, I've been adding empty spans like this

```
<span> </span>
```

to preserve white space between elements. 
However, the function doesn't seem to add them into `toWrap`, is there a fix for this?

Comment: the tag `<pre></pre>` preserves white spaces

Comment: Could you provide an example of white space you're trying to preserve?

Comment: rather than saving whitespace, have you just tried putting in &nbsp; for any place you need a space?  Or maybe just managing the space with the css?

Comment: I would try setting the `<span>`'s `display` property to `inline-block` in CSS

Comment: @NibbCNoble thanks, that sounds like a possibilty, css will probably be the way to go!